# How to order ordinal numbers

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

It is well-known that for $2$ ordinals $a$ and $b$ we have one of

$$a \in b, a=b \text{ or } b\in a$$

which is equivalent to $a$ or $b$ being subset of the other.

My issue is: when I have some particular ordinals, are there any general tips and/or tricks to order them?

Suppose I have the ordinals $a=\omega^2+\omega$ and $b=\omega+\omega^2$. What should I do so that I order them? (This is just an example I made up, might not be too enlightening)

We have $b=\omega+\omega^2=\omega(1+\omega)=\omega^2$, while $a=\bigcup_{c<a}\omega^2+c$ so if I have to guess, I'd say that $a>b$. However, I'm feeling quite uncomfortable in doing those types of questions, so if anyone could provide some insight, I'd be very grateful!

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, you could calculate their Cantor normal form. In this particular instance just note that $\omega^2 < \omega^2 + 1 < \sup \{ \omega^2 + n \mid n < \omega \} = \omega^2 + \omega$ (no guesswork required).

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is the Cantor normal form defined?

Comment: [Cantor Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Cantor_normal_form). (I would have cited it, if it wasn't the first hit using your favorite search engine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cantor normal form is indeed the right way to think about this. Let me try to give an "organic" explanation of why.

First, let's think about the **indecomposable ordinals**. An ordinal $\alpha$ is indecomposable if whenever we write $$\alpha=\beta+\gamma$$ with $\gamma\not=0$ (equivalently, with $\beta\not=\alpha$) we in fact have $\alpha=\gamma$. Some examples:

- $\omega$ is indecomposable: this is because [Finite]+[Finite]=[Finite], so [Finite]+[?]=[Infinite] implies [?] is infinite.
- $\omega+\omega$ is not indecomposable: this is because I've split it into two pieces, the second piece is $\omega$, and $\omega<\omega+\omega$. So **not every limit ordinal is indecomposable**.
- $\omega^2$ **is** indecomposable again - this is a good exercise.

It turns out that **the indecomposable ordinals are exactly the powers of $\omega$**. Now the following facts are crucial:

- If $\beta$ is indecomposable and $\alpha<\beta$, then $\alpha+\beta=\beta$. *Basically, indecomposable ordinals "absorb" smaller ordinals. Note that indecomposability is necessary: $\omega<\omega+\omega$, but $\omega+(\omega+\omega)\not=\omega+\omega$.* By (usual) induction, $\alpha\cdot n+\beta=\beta$ as well for finite $n$.
- Any ordinal $\alpha$ can be written uniquely as a nonincreasing sum of indecomposable ordinals.  *This is the **Cantor normal form** of that ordinal.*

These facts are proved by transfinite induction. Once we have them in hand, we can use them to add two ordinals: first convert the two ordinals into Cantor normal form using the second bullet point, then "smoosh" them together as appropriate using the first bullet point.

For example, to add $\omega+\omega^3\cdot 17+\omega\cdot 3$ and $\omega^2+1$ we would say:

$$(\color{red}{\omega+\omega^3\cdot 17}+\omega\cdot 3)+(\omega^2+1)=(\omega^3\cdot 17+\omega\cdot 3)+(\omega^2+1)=\omega^3\cdot 17+\color{red}{\omega\cdot3+\omega^2}+1=\omega^3\cdot 17+\omega^2+1.$$ (I've highlighted in red the portions which get "absorbed.") Note that all the transfinite induction/recursion stuff has been relegated to proving those crucial facts mentioned above; once we have those, manipulating ordinals is more or less automatic.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot!